# Making dojo dijit layout iOS compatible

Tags: javascript, ios, dojo, scroll, dijit.layout

I have a complex web application which is based on [`dijit.layout`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout.html). You will find a good example of the structure [here (check the examples)](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/BorderContainer.html#dijit-layout-bordercontainer).

As you can see there is no full page scrolling only scrolling inside the layout boxes. All layout areas have **`overflow:auto`**, which means they enable scrolling when the layout areas content is larger than the available area space.

The problem is, **iOS devices like iPad/iPhone/iPod touch don't support scrolling** inside HTML only for a full page.

Is there any generic way to make a digit.layout application compatible for iOS and other touch devices? For example extend the layout areas depending on the length of the content.

Comment: iOS devices do support scrolling inside HTML, you just need to use two fingers to scroll in those areas.

Answer (score 0):

did you already find a solution to this problem? I played around with a combination of dojox.mobile.ScrollableView and dijit.layout but end up having two scrollbars.

Comment: As Aaron B. Russell mentioned in the comment above, scrolling is possible on iOS! Using two fingers on this element...

Comment: Yeah, I am sure all users will know that, NOT.